# Python Value Types (int, float, str)

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I have an Excel sheet with the data as pictured:[Cisco Call Handlers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tseA.png)

I'm working with Python 3 and reading data from the Excel sheet but since it has both integers and strings, I cannot specify the data type. What's the best way to handle value types? At first, the integers would print of type "float" along with a trailing ".0" so I placed an apostrophe before the number of each cell and this resolved the issue but integers now print as type string. I want to build logic around the different types so what's the best way to go about this?
This is what I had in mind before I realized the integers now print as type string:

```
if type(value[x]) == str:
    do x
if type(value[x]) == int:
    do y
```

Another option I considered was to keep the type float and build logic around that but I would need regex help to remove the trailing `".0"` after each cell that had integers. 
This is what it would print before I placed apostrophes in each cell with numbers:

```
0 ['DisplayName', 'Extension', 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
```

value is created as follows:

```
values = dict()
for idx in range(1, xlrdsheet.nrows):
    values[idx] = xlrdsheet.row_values(idx)
for key, value in values.items():
    print(key, value)
```

Comment: How is `value` created? We need more details to point you to the "best" option...

Comment: yeah, I just figured that Thanks! Post has been updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you are reading these values from the Excel sheet as text:
You can use regex to check wether your value consists of numbers( `r"[0-9]*"`) or letters( `r"[a-bA-B]*"`) and convert it respectively. Or:

```
try:
    number = int(val)
except ValueError:
    text = val
```

Comment: thank you, I will try this and let you know if it works for my situation. I appreciate the speedy response

Comment: I used the try statement as my values that have letters also have numbers. Thanks again!

Comment: You could easily change that by saying there has to be at least one letter in the value that it counts as text or make it text if it's anything else than  pure numbers. Just look into the regex documentation, don't have the syntax in mind right now. I'd wager the regex to be better performance wise.